# Function<String, int> in Dart?

Tags: function, callback, dart

I have a function with a callback `void doSth(Function callback)`, however I would like to specify the parameters and return value of the callback like in Java.

Is this possible in Dart?
(I can't use Future here)

Comment: Yes it's possible. If you'd provide a concrete example what parameter type and return type you want then it would be easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void doSth(String Function callback(int /* type for parameter */ ))
```

See also https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-inline-function-types-over-typedefs